# How to save a temporary table per session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My main objective here would be to save a "temporary" table (data) per session. Working like the Session (HttpSessionStateBase).

Thing is, I need a configuration file to be loaded before anything. Save it (the xml data already parsed) somewhere to be accessed while that user (there is no login) is active and clear it after the browser is closed. And repeat all this again for a different session.

Comment: Can you please comment why can't you simply put "table" into `Session`? (Side note: there is no real "browser is closed" event - so you'd better drop your "clear it after the browser is closed" requirement. There are many posts around about it including SO).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov makes a good point - while you -can- try to intercept the event of a closing browser, your application should always provide for a graceful session shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do not exactly want it to "clear", honesly I just don't want it available for every person that opens the page at the same time (on difference computers, w/e). I could save it on session, but is it the best way? Thats my main issue.

Comment: I would say it is, @BrunoMonteiro. There are other options, but this approach seems to be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store objects on a Session context, like this:

```
SampleDataTableClass _obj = new SampleDataTableClass();
HttpContext.Current.Session["config"] = _obj;
```

But you mentioned that the data is reflecting a configuration file. Would the scope of that configuration be the same for all Sessions? In that case, you may want to check on the Application class:

```
Application["config"] = _obj;
```

Comment: I guess this is the best option then. Thank you. And it is per session. But thanks for the extra info! There's always something to learn.